# ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12

Tags: oracle

```
WHERE (ResTRRequest.RequestTime BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'HH')), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH') + INTERVAL '59:59' MINUTE TO SECOND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

I have above where condition in query when i execute it,it gives me hours must be between 1 to 12 due to static date I have given i.e ''2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'HH')' if I put sysdate the its working  fine but due to static date it gives me error.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let's break this down a bit:

```
WHERE (ResTRRequest.RequestTime
  BETWEEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'HH')), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
     AND TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH') + INTERVAL '59:59' MINUTE TO SECOND, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

In the first place, I don't think you mean this: `TRUNC(TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'HH'))`, I think maybe you mean this: `TRUNC(TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10'), 'HH')`. The number from 1-12 error comes from the fact that you have an hour of `20` and are trying to convert it into a date with the mask of `HH`. But as I said I think that's a typo. You can also use a `TIMESTAMP` literal here rather than `TO_DATE()`:

```
TRUNC(TIMESTAMP'2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'HH')
```

**Second, and just to get this out of the way, are you storing dates or timestamps as strings? *That's not a good idea.***

Third, it's not a good idea to use `BETWEEN` in date comparisons because you can miss the edge cases. It might be better to rewrite this as follows:

```
WHERE ( ResTRRequest.RequestTime >= TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10'), 'HH'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
    AND ResTRRequest.RequestTime < TO_CHAR(TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH') + INTERVAL '1' HOUR, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') )
```

Answer (score 16):

Problem is in mask:

```
TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'HH')
```

Replace with this one:

```
TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'HH24')
```

Comment: not working...

date format picture ends before converting entire input string.I got this working. I had already tried it with

Comment: Not working. I think this should be this instead: `TO_DATE('2012-12-01 20:10:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `ResTRRequest.RequestTime` is of a date type, this `Where` clause will work:

```
  where ResTRRequest.RequestTime
BETWEEN TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015-02-26 20:10:10', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH')
    AND TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'HH') + INTERVAL '59:59' MINUTE TO SECOND
```

If you have to compare character representations, keep in mind that you compare in lexicographic order, meaning that prefixes of strings are sorted before their strings! Avoid ensueing complications by using identical formatting models with componnents arranged in the order of decreasing significance. E.g.

```
 TO_CHAR(<whatever>, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

but not

```
 TO_CHAR(<whatever>, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's a safe assumption given the OP's code. It would certainly be better if `ResTRRequest.RequestTime` were of type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` though.

Comment: @DavidFaber I second your concern.

Answer (score 1):

If the language setting on Oracle is set for using the 12 hours time, this problem will occur when converting the 24 hours time format. 
There are two solutions to this :

1. Convert TIMESTAMP/DATE format in Oracle client

   alter session set nls_timestamp_format='YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF6';
2. Convert query to match 24hr format

   SELECT * FROM TEST_ WHERE DOB > TRUNC(TIMESTAMP'1970-01-01 20:10:10', 'HH');
   or

   SELECT * FROM TEST_ WHERE DOB > to_date('1970-01-01 20:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');

Answer (score 1):

Oracle defalts timestamps to 12h time system. You will need to indicate that it is a 00-24 hour system by add `24` to your format. See: `to_date('16/10/2023 00:00:22', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`

Notice that the `HH` has been changed to `HH24`.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to watch out for in the case you get this error is the data itself.
I've had date stored in xml tag that I had to parse and convert with TO_DATE with this format specifier 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM'. SQL broke with "ORA-01849: hour must be between 1 and 12" because some records were written like this: "12/20/2017 16:45:00 PM". Pay attention to 16h and PM specfier...